# How to convert duration of MM:SS to seconds in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, time, sum, google-sheets-formula, duration

As duration of a task, suppose that we have a column with cells formatted as `MM:SS` that would like to convert to seconds. Mathematically speaking, the solution is simple. We just need to compute `MM * 60 + SS` converting it to seconds. Additionally, we followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37859109/2371987) strategy to solve the problem. However, the direct way to solve it remains a question.

**What is the direct way to do it?**

Comment: The accepted answer at your link appears to be a fairly "direct" way, if your values are time values (and not just text strings). Could you edit your question to clarify what you mean by direct, and what kind of data you have?

Comment: By direct, it means the proper way. The solutions presented in that link do not provide enough context for this problem. Indeed, the provided and right answers are quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(TO_TEXT(A1:A), ":")*{60, 1},
 "select Col1+Col2 label Col1+Col2''"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but we are facing a problem now. The error says `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: Can't perform the function sum on values that are not numbers` on Google Sheets.

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sorry, it was our fault. It was a missed cell. Solved now. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: If you could provide some further explanation concerning your answer, it would be great. Good explanations make your answer even more important.

Answer (score 2):

All values are stored as days. 1 is one day. So the direct way to get seconds is just multiply by 24 hours/day, 60 minutes/hour and 60 seconds/minute. For eg, for 1 minute:

```
="0:1:0"*24*60*60
```

The underlying format is always `HH:MM:SS`. For `MM:SS`,  reduce the factor by 60:

```
="01:01"*24*60
```

*Note: This works because 1 hour in minutes is equal to 1 minute in seconds. But `01:01` by default, is considered 1 hour and 1 minutes by Google.*

Comment: We just need the `MM:SS` format, which is commonly different from the solutions we found. Yet, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto Just remove a `*60`. It should work for `MM:SS`.

Comment: Not really. The solution would be to remove both `*24` and `*60`, while adding the `+SS` amount.

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto Check my edit. It should fully work now.

Comment: It's great now! Much more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have hours:minutes and want to convert it to just be total seconds?

The answer is to multiply the time value (which is whole day increments) by 24 (hours per day), then by 60 (minutes per hour) and finally 60 again (seconds per minute). This assumes the times are stored in Excel time formatting (I use the time format with the 37 hours example in the dialog box, then removed the seconds from the custom string).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXbqD.png)