# How can I set a cell to highlight after X hours have passed in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, time, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet where a column is filled with times in a 24 hour format (XX:xx), how can I select a cell to highlight red after 3 hours have passed with conditional formatting?

I've been trying to mess with the Now() command in custom formulas for like 2 hours now, but I can't seem to get it to work. PLZ HELP!

Answer (score 2):

To Highlight cells if *exactly* 3 hours `03:00:00.000` have been passed you need to paste this formula in [format>conditional formating](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). > format cell if - Custom Formula, take a look at the example in [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19epktMvrSTFM9QuFDpPoSkouiG33f_gd_Anv-zuLZcc/edit?usp=sharing).

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,IF(A3:A-NOW()>0.13,"True","False") ))
```

`A3:A-NOW()>0.13` to check if the date in the range `A3:A` minus [`NOW()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?hl=en) is greater than `0.13` which represent an hour `03:00:00.000` as a number.

[image]

To check and highlight cells when certain duration have been passed and be able to adjust the duration from a cell you need to paste this formula in cell `B2` to get True or False output.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IF(A2:A-NOW()>$E$2,"True","False")))
```

It can be used as a `formula` in [format>conditional formating](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).
take a look at the example in [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19epktMvrSTFM9QuFDpPoSkouiG33f_gd_Anv-zuLZcc/edit?usp=sharing).
the columns highlighted in blue is for demonstration it can be deleted.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make this formula work without the date? I have been trying to find a way for cells to highlight automatically after 3 hours have passed while using timestamps (Ctrl+Alt+;) that just have the time in a 24 hour format (14:30)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has the same issue, it has been solved. Looks like the Now() call requires both the time and date to be inside the cell in order to work.

The formula I used to highlight cells that are older than 3 hours is
=(Now()-TIME(3,0,0))

A friend also showed me a different formula that seems to do the same thing
=IF(NOW()>A2+3/24,TRUE(),FALSE())

You can change the time by changing the (3,0,0) to Hrs,Min,Sec of your choosing, for the second formula, you can change it by adjusting the fraction value (3/24 for 3 hours, etc)

These will only work if you have the date and time in the cells you are formatting (e.g. If you timestamp with Ctrl+Alt+Shift+;) it will not work if you timestamp with just the time (Ctrl+Alt+Shift) as that seems to set the year to 1899 for some reason.

It would be nice if I could get these working without a date, but I have not found a way to do that.

Comment: Please improve your answer and provide further information. The answer is not clear nor informative. If you need, you can find similar ways ([stackoverflow.com/a/72822277/2371987](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72822277/2371987)) to properly address a question in this community.